# IIS 5.1 on XP Classic ASP appears to be in single threaded mode

Tags: asp-classic, iis-5

I do'nt have script debugging enabled on IIS 5.1 on XP, but the Classic ASP applications appear to be running in single threaded mode. One page must finish loading before another can load.

Any ideas???

Comment: Your question is better suited for serverfault.com

Comment: You should post details about your IIS configuration, the application pool settings especially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike is right, Classic ASP responses are returned in order of receipt (not simultaneously) when being requested by the same session.

If you need to do two requests at the same time in the same browser (as your web visitors might need to do if say one of the requests is for an image or AJAX) you can disable session state for a page request using 
`<%@ EnableSessionState=False %>` at the top of your ASP page. For more information, see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244465

When you do this however, you don't have access to the Session object, so you will need to consider some other way of identifying the user in such pages (e.g. a token on the query string, IP address, custom implemented session state using the Cookie object and a database, etc)

If you aren't using the Session object at all, it can be disabled in IIS all together, also explained at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244465

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you run this tests from different clients.  Asp will serialize the pages when they are being requested by the same session.  To test multiple simultanious access you need two browsers that are not using the same session. I find this easiest to do by using 2 different types of browsers at the same time like firefox and safari.